# Main laptop display not working with NVIDIA Drivers on 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I recently upgraded my HP laptop (HP Pavilion Power 15-cb040nd) to Ubuntu 18.04. I had previously been running Ubuntu 16.04 and that was working flawlessly, but during the installation process already it started giving me issues. In this case it was solved by adding "nomodeset" to Grub after installation.

The real problem, however, occurs when I want to connect my external monitor to my HDMI port. I installed the NVIDIA drivers (currently on 418, but I've tried it with 390, 410 and 430), using [this tutorial](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-To-Install-Ubuntu-18-04-with-NVIDIA-Drivers-and-any-Desktop-Flavor-1178/). I went through the whole process with my department's SysAdmin and he basically confirmed that it appeared to be installed correctly. However, when I run `nvidia-smi` in the terminal, I get 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgiav.png). The biggest red flag (to me) seems to be: `00000000:01:00.0 Off` and `0MiB/4040MiB`. The very first attempt at installing the drivers was through `Software & Updates` and `Additional Drivers`.

One possible solution I found was to add `Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"` to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`. I did this and when I reboot my laptop's main screen freezes at the sda cleanup, but now my external monitor suddenly comes to life and shows the login screen. I login and then suddenly it seems like my laptop runs flawlessly. Everything is very smooth, e.g. changing workspaces is a fluid animation instead of instantaneous. `nvidia-smi` gives the right feedback too. However, I cannot get my laptop's main screen to work like this, which is problematic if I want to work and I don't have an external screen (and the fact that I like working with two screens at the same time). I've tried rebooting without the external monitor connected and then it just freezes on the reboot. Connecting the monitor then instantly gives me the login screen; I've done this with two different monitors too. Removing this line gets me back to where I started (empty `nvidia-smi` and it doesn't recognize the external monitor).

When I go to `tty`, my laptop's screen is responsive again, but when I go back with `CTRL+ALT+F1` the external screen is the only responsive one and the laptop hangs on whatever I had last in `tty`.

So, what else can I do to have both screens and the NVIDIA drivers working?

Replying to Marmayogi (after upgrading to nvidia-driver-430):

```
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

$ test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"
efi

$ lspci -knn | grep -A2 -i -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:836b]
Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [103c:836b]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia

$ dkms status
nvidia, 430.09, 4.18.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv0000103Csd0000836Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

In Grub:
$videoinfo
List of supported video modes:
Legend: mas/position=red/green/blue/reserved
Adapter `Bochs PCI Video Driver':
  No info available
Adapter `Cirrus CLGD 5446 PCI Video Driver':
  No info available
Adapter `EFI GOP driver':
* 0x000 1920 x 1080 x 32 (7680)  Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
  0x001  640 x  480 x 32 (2560)  Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
  0x002  800 x  600 x 32 (3200)  Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
  0x003 1024 x  768 x 32 (4096)  Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
  0x004 1280 x 1024 x 32 (5120)  Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8  pos: 16/8/0/24
Adapter `EFI UGA driver':
  No info available

$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep -i GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93088/discussion-on-question-by-eduardh-main-laptop-display-not-working-with-nvidia-dr).